# Angular JS drop down to show dynamic content using ng-click and ng-show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my HTML: I am trying to build both the menu and the content shown from the menu in angular js with an object called contests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />

  <title>Title Town!</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ContestController as contest">

    <h2>{{contest.greeting}}</h2>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a team!
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="contest in contest.contest" ng-class="{{contest.active}}"><a href ng-click="tab = tab=={{contest.id}} ? a : {{contest.id}}">{{contest.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p ng-repeat="contest in contest.contest" ng-show="{{contest.show}}">{{contest.name}} Contest!  </p>           
    </div>

   <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><p>There should be content displayed above me when a team is clicked. </p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript. You will see that I have created a controller called contest.  I created an object and assigned it to "this.contest = contests". When I inspect my code, everything is loaded properly but there are errors and there isn't too much of a description.. And of course when I click a team name, the paragraph that is supposed to show isn't showing.

Syntax Error: Token 'contest.id' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

```
// Code goes here

//main Controller
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('ContestController', function($scope) {
    this.greeting = 'Welcome my app!';
    this.contest = contests;

    $scope.tab = '1';

   /* $scope.toggle() = function(id){

        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
        console.log('Test' + id);

    };*/

  });

  var contests = [{
        name: 'Seahawks',
        active: '{active:tab === 1}',
        show: 'tab === 1',
        id: '1'
    },{
        name: 'Colts',
        active: '{active:tab===2}',
        show: 'tab === 2',
        id: '2'
    },{
        name: 'Badgers',
        active: '{active:tab===3}',
        show: 'tab === 3',
        id: '3'
    },{
        name: 'Rams',
        active: '{active:tab===4}',
        show: 'tab === 4',
        id: '4'
    }];

})();
```

My [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVVz9b87NeyPZ70DCKwh?p=preview)

Comment: I've gone ahead and rewritten this for you (http://plnkr.co/edit/MlOzNqqcrIh7xImysIbU?p=preview)

Comment: @MikeCheel I'll definitely give you an upvote if you make it as answer

Comment: I also will. Thanks for the answer @jyrkim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented I've rewritten your code for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/MlOzNqqcrIh7xImysIbU?p=preview

**Controller**:

```
(function () {

        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .controller('ContestController', [ContestController]);

    function ContestController() {
        var self = this;

        self.data = {
            greeting: 'Welcome my app!',
            contests: [
                {
                    name: 'Seahawks',
                    id: 1
                }, {
                    name: 'Colts',
                    id: 2
                }, {
                    name: 'Badgers',
                    id: 3
                }, {
                    name: 'Rams',
                    id: 4
                }
            ],
            currentTab: 0
        };

        self.data.selectTab = function (tab) {
            self.data.currentTab = tab;
        }
    }
})();
```

**Html**:

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="ContestController as contest">

        <h2>{{contest.data.greeting}}</h2>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a team!
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="c in contest.data.contests">
                    <a href ng-click="contest.data.selectTab(c.id)">{{c.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p ng-show="contest.data.currentTab > 0">{{contest.data.contests[contest.data.currentTab - 1].name}} Contest!</p>
        </div>

        <p>There should be content displayed above me when a team is clicked. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

A few things to note:

1) You should strive to put a '.' between all of your controller properties and their data (e.g. use an object property instead of just setting primitives. This is why in my rewrite I assign everything to a data object property.

2) You were using binding expressions where they don't belong. For example, in ng-click and ng-show. Angular was getting confused.

3) You were also trying to use binding like expressions in your controller with the 'active' property that I don't believe will translate the way you thought it would.

4) It is considered best practice to place your css links in the head of your document and your javascript tags just before the body tag. You also had two links pointing to bootstrap's css.

If you have any questions about my example feel free to comment!

Comment: Thanks a lot mike. I am about a week into this angular stuff but I think it's really useful.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. As I said, feel free to ask questions about the code and I will try to answer them.